# Proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, solution-verification

> **"The number $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number."**
>
> *Proof.* Suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.
>
> Let $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of all prime numbers.
>
> It follows that,
>
> \begin{equation} \sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q} \text{ where p,q $\in
> > \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$} \end{equation}
>
> By squaring both sides of the equation, one obtains:
>
> \begin{equation} 2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} \end{equation}
>
> From
>
> \begin{equation} 2q^2 = p^2, \end{equation}
>
> it follows that,
>
> \begin{equation} p^2 = 2r \text{ where r $\in \mathbb{Z^+}$}.
> > \end{equation}
>
> From
>
> \begin{equation} q^2 = \frac{p^2}{2}, \end{equation}
>
> it follows that,
>
> \begin{equation} q^2 = 2s \text{ where s $\in \mathbb{Z^+}$}.
> > \end{equation}
>
> Because, for every positive even integers 2$\phi$ where $\phi \in
> > \mathbb{Z^+}$,
>
> \begin{equation}  2\phi =  uv \text{ where $u \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $v
> > \in \mathbb{P}$ ,} \end{equation}
>
> it follows that,
>
> \begin{equation} 2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{2r}{2s} = \frac{ax}{by}
> > \text{ where a,b $\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, $b \ne 0$, and $x,y \in
> > \mathbb{P}$}. \end{equation}
>
> Consider the equation:
>
> \begin{equation}  x = 2\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)y \end{equation}
>
> Because the $LHS$ of the above equation is a prime number and the
> $RHS$ is not a prime number, one obtains a contradiction.
>
> Hence, the number $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.

---

**I have realized that the proof I had demonstrated before is incorrect, so I have put the incorrect proof in the above blockquote. The new proof is in the texts below.**

---

I am trying to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number on my own using proof by contradiction. However, I am not sure whether my proof is correct or not.

The following is my proof.

---

**"The number $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number."**

Proof. Suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.

It follows that there must be an integer $p$ and a nonzero integer $q$ such that:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2} &= \frac{p}{q}
\end{align}

By squaring both sides of the above equation, one obtains:

\begin{align}
2 &= \frac{p^2}{q^2}
\end{align}

Rearranging the above equation so that $p^2$ is the subject, one obtains:

\begin{align}
p^2 &= 2q^2
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
p^2 = 2r \text{ where r $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^+}$}
\end{align}

Also, from the equation $2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$, by rearranging the equation so that $q^2$ is the subject, one obtains:

\begin{align}
q^2 = \frac{p^2}{2}
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
q^2 = 2s \text{ where s $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^+}$}
\end{align}

Substituting $2r$ and $2s$ into the equation $2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$, one obtains:

\begin{align}
2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{2r}{2s}
\end{align}

Since $p^2 = 2q^2$, it follows that $p^2 > q^2$.

Because both $p^2$ and $q^2$ are positive even numbers and $q^2 \geq 4$, it follows that $p^2 \geq 16$.

Thus, the equation $2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{2r}{2s}$ is expressed as:

\begin{align}
2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{(4+2m)^2}{(2+2n)^2} \text{ where m,n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^*}$ }
\end{align}

Because the term $\frac{(4+2m)^2}{(2+2n)^2} = \frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2}$ and $n \leq m+1$ for $\frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2}$ to be an integer, it follows that:

\begin{align}
2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{(4+2m)^2}{(2+2n)^2} = \frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2} \text{ where m,n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z^*}$ and $n \leq m+1$}
\end{align}

Expanding $(m+2)^2$ as $m^2 +4m + 4$ and factor $2$ from the term, one obtians:

\begin{align}
\frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{(m^2 +4m +4)}{(n^2 +2n +1)} = \frac{2(\frac{m^2}{2}+ 2m + 2)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} = 2 \text{ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $n \leq m+1$}
\end{align}

For the term $\frac{2(\frac{m^2}{2}+ 2m + 2)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)}$ to be equal to $2$, $\frac{(\frac{m^2}{2}+ 2m + 2)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} =1$.

For $\frac{m^2}{2}+ 2m + 2$ to be an integer, $m=2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z^*}$.

Thus,

\begin{align}
1 = \frac{(\frac{m^2}{2}+ 2m + 2)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} = \frac{(2k^2+ 4k + 2)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} = \frac{2(k^2+ 2k + 1)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} \text{ where $k,n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $n \leq 2k +1$}
\end{align}

Assuming there exists $k,n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$ such that $k^2 + 2k +1$ equals to the number $1$ and $n^2 + 2n +1$ equals to the prime number $2$.

Such $k,n$ make the term $\frac{2(k^2+ 2k + 1)}{(n^2 + 2n +1)} = 1$.

Because $n^2 +2n +1 \ne 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^*}$, one obtains a contradiction.

Hence, the number $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square root of $2$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382318/square-root-of-2-is-irrational)

Comment: Based on what you wrote, $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{x}{2y}$, so I don't believe there is a contradiction to derive. (I.e. the RHS is a prime number, it is $x$). I think the issue here is that $\frac{b}{a}$ is not necessarily an integer, hence it is not possible to deduce that the RHs is composite.

Comment: You must have a misprint: you appear to use $q^2=2s$, but introduced $s$ in the claim $p^2=2s$.

Comment: How do you know $2\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)y$ isn’t a prime number? Maybe it’s $2\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)11$, say.

Comment: @SteveKass I know where I have made a mistake now. I have not consider the term $\frac{b}{a}$ as $\frac{1}{2}$ when I tying to prove this making my proof incorrect.

Comment: @J.G. I have edited my original post and have posted a new proof. Is the new proof correct? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @Approxiz How do you know $(m+2)^2=2(n+1)^2$ has no solutions?

Comment: @J.G. If I were to factor out $2$ from $(m+2)^2$, I obtained $2(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}} +\sqrt{2})^2$. Then the term $\frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2}$ becomes $\frac{2(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}} +\sqrt{2})^2}{(n+1)^2}$. Because for $\frac{2(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}} +\sqrt{2})^2}{(n+1)^2}$ to become $2$, the term $\frac{(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}} +\sqrt{2})^2}{(n+1)^2}$ must be $1$. However, no integer $m$ could make the term $(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}} +\sqrt{2})^2$ an integer, so there should not be a solution to $(m+2)^2 = 2(n+1)^2$.

Comment: @J.G. I do not know whether the above statement can be put in the prove or not because I am proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: @Approxiz You don't know $m+2=(n+1)\sqrt{2}$ is impossible until you've proven $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @J.G. In this case, I need to explain further that why the last equation in my proof has no solution or that the equation is incorrect?

Comment: @Approxiz Once you've proven $p,\,q$ are both even, you should finish the proof the usual way (by noting this implies $p/q$ has no in-lowest-terms expression, which is impossible for rational numbers.) What you've tried doesn't look like it gets you anywhere.

Comment: @J.G. I have coded the equation in Python and it turns out that the equation seems to be true (at least for $m,n$ in range($100$)). Is there a way to prove or disprove the last equation? Sorry for asking many questions. I am trying to learn proof-writing on my own.

Comment: @Approxiz It's equivalent to the original problem, so you're really asking how prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, given that your approach doesn't work. I've already advised you of one way to do this, which starts largely as per your strategy. A few proofs are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality).

Comment: @masiewpao Sorry for asking another question after you have answered this question for some time ago. I have made a final attempt to prove that $\frac{(m+2)^2}{(n+1)^2} \ne 2$ in order to prove that the number $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. Is my current proof a proof or a conjecture? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

It is all fine up until you introduce $2\phi = uv$. Fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that $2\phi$ is already a product of powers of prime numbers. Then $v$ is just one specific prime that makes up $2\phi$ and does not tell us much about $2r/2s$.
To continue the proof, observe that $p^2 = 2r$ and $q^2 = 2s$ are both even numbers and $2|p^2,q^2$. But for $\sqrt{2}$ to be rational, we need that $\text{gcd}(p,q)=\text{gcd}(p^2,q^{2}) = 1$, which is not what we get. Hence, a contradiction and the proof is complete.